# MySQL query to return n'th lag from latest observation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following MySQL table:

```
firm | Sales | year
A    | 100   | 2018
A    | 200   | 2017
A    | 300   | 2016
B    | 400   | 2017
B    | 500   | 2016
B    | 600   | 2015
C    | 700   | 2016
C    | 800   | 2015
C    | 900   | 2014
```

I am trying to write MySQL query that will return last observation (Sales) or n'th lag from last observation, for every group (firm).

I have found MySQL query to return last observation for every group:

```
select * 
from (select * from mytable order by `Group`, firm, datum desc) x
group by `Group`
```

but I don't know how to modify the code to return one lag from latest observation, that is:

```
firm | Sales | year
A    | 200   | 2017
B    | 500   | 2016
C    | 800   | 2015
```

Comment: which version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Server version: 5.6.39 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL-only solution? If so, the `[r]` tag is superfluous (especially since your question has no R code). The fact that you are using R to execute the query is not critical here. If you can use R code, then `dbplyr` could almost certainly do this "well".

Comment: I have removed r tag, sorry. I thought I would try to find solution inside R, but it is really only MySQL thing.

Comment: I see you've accepted an answer which is great, but this is also quite feasible in R itself. Some might say it's even easier than SQL. If you have more complicated needs that this question/answer no longer address, you might consider restating it in an R-flavor, perhaps using `dplyr`/`dbplyr`.

Comment: I agree, but I ave to send queries to Mysql database,

Comment: There's no `group` here (thank heavens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most general method is to enumerate the values using variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@f = t.firm, @rn + 1,
                        if(@f := t.firm, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from mytable t cross join
           (select @f := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by t.firm, t.year desc
     ) t
where rn = 2;
```

Your version has a fatal flaw:  it is using `group by` with `select *`.  You have unaggregated columns in the select that are not `group by` keys.  This is broken SQL and will fail in almost any database and using the default settings in the more recent versions of MySQL.

If the intention is that "n" is the number of years before the latest year (well, offset by 1), then joins can work:

```
select t.*
from mytable t join
     (select firm, max(year) as max_year
      from mytable
      group by firm
     ) f
     on t.firm = f.firm and t.year = f.max_year - (2 - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, think it works, I tried second code only, it looks easier. Can you show how to include where clause, should I put it in "inside" table?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use LAG with the Windowing Functions introduced in MySQL 8